# Compiling GTK2 from source

Tags: 11.10, gnome, gtk, install-from-source

I download and try to compile the source code for GTK2:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep libgtk2.0-0
sudo apt-get source libgtk2.0-0   
cd gtk+2.0-2.24.6/

./configure --prefix=/usr
make
```

And I get an error:

```
In file included from gtkquery.c:26:0:
gtkquery.h:31:2: error: #error "gtkfilechooserprivate.h is not supported API for general use"
```

Interestingly, I can compile GTK3 with no problems at all with the same steps above. I am using Oneiric.

If i try `debuild`, I get thousands of

```
dpkg-source: error: cannot represent change to gtk+2.0-2.24.6/something/something: binary file contents changed
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the source package that you've downloaded has pre-set flags that are passed to configure, along with a number of other steps that are laid out in `debian/rules`.
Prior to building, if you've made changes to the package you should add a new revision in `debian/changelog`

To build the source package that you've downloaded:

```
sudo apt-get install devscripts build-essential
cd gtk+2.0-2.24.6/
debuild
```

This will compile & produce binary packages from the build in the parent directory.

Comment: This gives me "dpkg-source: error: unrepresentable changes to source
" By the way the steps I did works for GTK3 so they should be working for GTK2 too.